# DateDiff Returning Dates and Not Integer Values

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I've added a `[DAYS_FROM_TODAY]` column to my table to calculate the number of days between today's date and the date a check was written for each record in that table.

I used the following code to update the table:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Unpaid]
SET [DAYS_FROM_TODAY] = DATEDIFF(dd, CHECK_DATE, GETDATE())
```

However when I look at the top 1,000 records of the `[dbo].[Unpaid]` table, the `[DAYS_FROM_TODAY]` column has the following appearance instead of integers:

```
DAYS_FROM_TODAY

1900-09-03 00:00:00.000

1900-01-23 00:00:00.000
```

---

Both the `CHECK_DATE` and `DAYS_FROM_TODAY` columns are datetime types.
Am I missing an important step?

Comment: Why are you doing `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: @Kin I need to know how long all unpaid checks that we've sent out to respective organizations, have been outstanding.

Comment: Then it should be a select .. not an update without a `where` clause. Depending on the table size, it can take a while and can fill up your T-log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's converting the integer to a datetime- the column is a datetime.

You're seeing the datetime conversion of the results of the DATEDIFF function. Implicit conversion from integer to datetime is in days beginning with 1/1/1900 as 0.

```
  SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME)
```

Returns

```
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

If you want to store the integer result in the column, just change the data type to integer.